# Comparing the time of a symlink

Tags: bash, shell-script, symlink, timestamps

I want to check whether link `lnkfile` is older than a regular reference file `reffile`.

The bash `test` builtin dereferences links, so `test lnkfile -ot reffile` compares the target of `lnkfile`, not the link itself.

Is there a way to make the `test` builtin not follow symlinks? Otherwise, how can I compare the time of a symlink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way with `test`, but you could use `find`.

```
test "$(find reffile -prune -newer lnkfile)" && command
```

Here, `find` returns output if `lnkfile` is older than `reffile`. `test` without an option is equivalent to `test -n`. This is true if the length of the string is nonzero. Hence, if there is output from `find`, `command` is executed.

---

In the comments, I was asked to make a comparison of this solution vs. [`stat`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495865/18887). Firstly, I find the `stat` approach perfectly fine.

I did a benchmark to compare. I repeated the test a few times, alternating, and got similar results.

```
$ time (for i in {1..1000}; do test "$(stat --format=%Z a)" -lt "$(stat --format=%Z b)" && echo foo > /dev/null ; done)

================
CPU 101%
CPU 104%
user    1.264
system  0.942
total   2.108

$ time (for i in {1..1000}; do test "$(find b -newer a)" && echo foo > /dev/null ; done)

================
CPU 104%
user    0.693
system  0.526
total   1.164
```

I looks like `find` is almost twice as fast, perhaps because it's a single process rather than two `stats`? I'm not sure how else to compare them; please comment if there are other relevant aspects you can think of.

Here are some other differences, as per Stéphane Chazelas's comments below:

> Other differences are: the `find` one is standard. while the `stat` one needs the GNU implementation of `stat`. The `stat` one won't work for files modified within the same second (while `find` should work on systems where sub-second granularity for timestamps is supported). Neither `find` nor `stat` support arbitrary file names.
>
> You'll find other differences if either of the files cannot be `stat()`ed.

Comment: What `test` implementation do you have that does not have `-n`?  It's a standard option...  Also quote the command substitution.

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm just confirming that no options is identical to `-n`, so it's easier to grep the `man`. Good point with the quote. Thanks.

Comment: I misunderstood what you were saying about `-n` and read it as "there is no `-n` option" instead of "`test` without an option is the same as `test -n`".

Comment: @Kusalananda Ah got it. I edited to clarify my ambiguous language. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Now I'm well embarrassed with two valid answers: what do you think about Chris Down's solution? Especially in re efficiency, since I'll have scores of link-and-file pairs to test.

Comment: @L.Levrel The other answer is perfectly fine IMO. I did a benchmark, but I'm not sure if there are other aspects that might be relevant.

Comment: Thank you, I'm convinced. It's striking to see how the process calls dominate the total overhead of these loops!

Comment: Second thought: what if they have the same date? Then `lnkfile` is not older, but `lnkfile ! -newer reffile` is true, right? So I'd rather use `reffile -newer lnkfile`.

Comment: @L.Levrel Oops! You are perfectly correct. I fixed the answer and re-benchmarked

Comment: Other differences are: the `find` one is standard. while the `stat` one needs the GNU implementation of `stat`. The `stat` one won't work for files modified within the same second (while `find` should work on systems where sub-second granularity for timestamps is supported). Neither `find` nor `stat` support arbitrary file names.

Comment: You'll find other differences if either of the files cannot be `stat()`ed.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and edit @StéphaneChazelas. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Is `-prune` really necessary since `reffile` is a regular file? (I understand the intention of making the command robust if someone else inadvertently uses it on a directory.)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, bash doesn't offer any versions of `-ot` (and the like) which avoid dereferencing symlinks.

What you can do instead is use GNU stat (which doesn't dereference symbolic links without `-L`) and compare their mtime epochs numerically:

```
if (( "$(stat --format=%Z lnkfile)" < "$(stat --format=%Z reffile)" )); then
    # lnkfile is older
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Now I'm well embarrassed with two valid answers: what do you think about Sparhawk's solution? Especially in re efficiency, since I'll have scores of link-and-file pairs to test.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` 5.6 or above (for the nanosecond precision), you could do it with builtins only with:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
if 
  stat -LA lnktime -F '%021s%N' +mtime -- $lnkfile &&
    stat -A reftime -F '%021s%N' +mtime -- $reffile &&
    [[ $lnktime < $reftime ]]
then
  print -r -- $lnkfile is older than $reffile
fi
```

Which would work regardless of what characters or non-characters the file names contain and compare timestamps down to the nanosecond.

We're comparing the timestamps as strings (number of nanoseconds as a decimal string representation zero-padded to 30 digits) instead of floating points because the typical double precision floating points of a x86_64 PC running GNU/Linux at least don't have enough precision to store numbers like `1548195897.775033155` so you would not be able to tell apart two files modified today within the same 100 nanoseconds.

```
$ ((1548195897.775033155 < 1548195897.775033255)) && echo yes
$ [[ 1548195897775033155 < 1548195897775033255 ]] && echo yes
yes
```

Comment: Thank you for the details. Could you expand about "non-characters" please? I've tested with a filename containing newline: GNU `stat` shows no problem. `find` will replace the newline with `?` if output goes to the terminal, otherwise it is preserved (which is the case in Sparhawk's answer, but anyway we're just testing if there's any output, so `?` would be fine). All substitutions are double-quoted to avoid word splitting.